# article twoside margins different to oneside

Tags: geometry, double-sided, single-sided

I'm writing a paper for my Bachelor graduation. First i used `oneside`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, headsepline, footsepline, onside]{article}
\usepackage[verbose, showframe, left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

The output is:
[image]

But because i have to bind my paper, i decided to use `twoside` with different odd/even page margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, headsepline, footsepline, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[verbose, showframe, left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

The Output is irritating. The margin between the headlines are bigger now **for some pages**. The spaces in general are bigger, as you can see:

[image]

Also some Enums are a bit creepy:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item \auswahl{Active Directory Domänendienste}
 \item \auswahl{DSN-Server}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Other enums are looking fine:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item \auswahl{Active Directory Domänendienste}
 \item \auswahl{DNS-Server}
 \item \auswahl{Hyper-V}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

The only thing i changed was the `oneside` to `twoside`, but i dont know which `length` i should change.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in twoside `\flushbottom` is the default, so that on a two page spread the bottom baseliens match, it seems you want to restore `\raggedbottom` which is the default in `oneside` so put `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks! Thats it!